# c++ static struct does not name a type

Tags: c++, struct, static

In ClassA.h I define a struct pointer like:

```
 struct timestr
 {
  uint64_t timestart;
  uint64_t timeend;
 };

 static timestr *extime;
```

And in the ClassA.cpp, I initialize like:

```
timestr *ClassA::extime = NULL;
```

however I got error: timestr does not name a type. What is wrong here?

Comment: Is the `timestr` struct outside the `ClassA` class and the `extime` variable inside? That's the way you're using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the `timestr` structure is inside the containing class, in which case you need to use the scoping for that too:

```
ClassA::timestr *ClassA::extime = NULL;
```